# Jquery Validation - How to validade a dynamic form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, dynamic-forms

I'm new to Jquery Validation(http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

I've a dynamic form. I need to know if it possible to validate a form like this:

```
<form ...>
<div class="multi-city">                        
    <div class="controls visible">
        <label for="id_form-0-city_input">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-0-city_input" class="city-input ui-autocomplete-input" id="id_form-0-city_input" autocomplete="off">
        <p style=""><a href="#" class="delete">Remove</a></p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-0-city" name="form-0-city">

    <div class="controls visible">
        <label for="id_form-1-city_input">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-1-city_input" class="city-input ui-autocomplete-input" id="id_form-1-city_input" autocomplete="off">
        <p style=""><a href="#" class="delete">Remove</a></p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-1-city" name="form-1-city">

    <div class="controls hidden">
        <label for="id_form-2-city_input">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-2-city_input" class="city-input ui-autocomplete-input" id="id_form-2-city_input" autocomplete="off">
        <p style=""><a href="#" class="delete">Remove</a></p>
    </div>                                    
</div>
</form>
```

Basically I need to validade the ".controls.visible". By code:

```
$('.multi-city .controls.visible')
```

What strategy should I use to validade this dynamic fields?

Any ideas?

Best Regards,

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] tag is for a totally different plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking.  *By default*, this plugin will simply ignore any hidden fields.  If those fields aren't truly "hidden", then you'll need to dynamically edit your rules as you create or "remove" (hide?) these fields.  The only way to do such manipulation is with the methods already built in to the plugin...

- `rules('add')`
- `rules('remove')`

See documentation for all:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Plugin_methods

---

To add rules to dynamically added fields, you would use [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) right after a field is created.

```
$('[name="Field2"]').rules('add', {
    required:true,
    messages: {
        required: "Custom message."
    }
});
```

Or for many new fields at once, use the "starts with" selector and `.each`...

```
$('[name^="Field"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required:true,
        messages: {
            required: "Custom message."
        }
    });
});
```

Simple demo of this method:  http://jsfiddle.net/xCY4T/1/

---

Another way would be to *create* a `class` using [the addClassRules method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#namerules).

```
$.validator.addClassRules("MyRule", {
    required: true
});
```

Then when you create the new fields, make sure they each contain a `class="MyRule"` along with a unique `name`, of course.

```
<input type="text" name="Field1" class="MyRule" />
<input type="text" name="Field2" class="MyRule" />
```

This method is very easy but I see no way to over-ride the default messages.

Simple demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/xCY4T/3/